# Deployed Rails app always coming up in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

Using Rails 3.0.1, Apache 2.2.9, and Passenger 3.0.0 on Debian.

For some mysterious reason, the Rails app is coming up in the development environment. I've double-checked the Apache configuration, the VirtualHost files, and so forth, and there are zero instances of "RailsEnv" or "RAILS_ENV" either in /etc/apache2 or in the app directory itself.

Worse, even if I *do* put a "RailsEnv production" line into the Directory block in the VirtualHost file, it makes absolutely no difference, and the app still comes up in the development environment.

Nothing interesting is logged if I set PassengerLogLevel to 1.

Any help either with what the problem is, or at least a course of action to identify the problem, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Passenger 3 is the latest final version. Try to use it before submitting a problem.

Comment: Swapped from older apt-get Passenger to current 3.0.0 gem; problem still remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because with config.ru your app is detected as a Rack app, not a Rails app, and thus you need to set RackEnv instead of RailsEnv. A "Rails" app refers to a "Rails 1 or 2" app. Rails 3 apps are considered to be Rack apps.

Comment: With that info in hand, I discovered that some goof put "RackEnv development" in an .htaccess file. Removing that let the default production environment occur fine. Thanks much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After thrashing around for a while and trying random things off the 'net, I've found that deleting the config.ru file Rails generated solves the problem without otherwise causing the app to cease functioning. Why this was causing the problem remains unknown to me, but anybody coming across this having the same issue might try that solution.

Answer (score 0):

Same symptom here, but none of the suggested solutions work for me.  I first noticed this when I set my `<body>` tag to be `<body class="<%= Rails.env %>">` and defining a background-color for the development class that is distinctly different from the background-color in the production class.  All I ever see (production & development) is the development color.  And of course viewing the source of the web page in the browser shows that the class being generated is development.  I renamed config.ru to ~config.ru and restarted Apache2 and that didn't have an impact.  I added RackEnv production to my *:80 virtual host file where the other Passenger attributes are set.  That didn't have an impact. So I reset ~config.ru to be config.ru, restarted Apache2 and still don't see a change.  I appreciate the explanation given by @Hongli of a Rack startup versus a Rails startup.  I just wish my server would listen to him! I even did a recursive listing grepping for .htaccess -- none found.  At least I think I know now where to keep poking around.

---

Apache 2.2.15, Rails 3.0.3, Passenger 3.0.2, Mac OS X Server 10.6.6

Comment: To follow up on my technique, I set `RackEnv production` in my virtual host file, and then in my app/views/layout/application.html.erb file I set `<body class="<%= ENV['RACK_ENV'] || "development" %>">` to achieve the desired effect of having the production environment use a background color that differs from the background color in development.